# Allegro5 with C - making program

Tags: c, oop, allegro, allegro5

I'm making program using Allegro5, but I'm not familiar with the library yet. I just want to know what is possible with this library.

I have to do 'color correction of image' (contrast, brightness, etc.) and I thought about:

-making buttons (like in normal windows program),

-scrollbars,

-file loader - I click on the button and I'm allowed to jump through directories on my hard drive and pick image file i want to edit in my program

-opening windows in allegro window (for the preview or something)

etc.

I want to use for that as much OOP as I can (i know, it's C). Is it possible to do all of that in C and Allegro5, or i need windows libraries and other stuff as well?

Thanks in advance for your replies. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do all of those things, but Allegro 5 is primarily designed for games and not GUI applications. It has support for native menus (5.1 series) and dialogs, but you're on your own regarding buttons, sliders, etc. (There are some third party GUI libraries available, but none of them would look like a native application.)

So if your program is basically a GUI application, then you're probably best off using something like Qt or GTK as your foundation, and only using a graphics library as needed.

Comment: I have to use Allegro5 library in my project, but I think it could be used for the color correction only. I'm not sure if I can use libraries, that aren't included in C already. I could always do the core of my program in console and pass file paths as arguments, but it's really ugly way to do it. I'm not told to make GUI, but I think it's obvious to use that.

Comment: I have a following question: can I use Allegro 5.0.7 and add "native_dialog" addon from 5.1.4 to it and it will work? I've already built allegro 5.1.4 with CMake and MSVC and I wonder what to do with the generated files. :P

Comment: The addons will not work on prior versions. Building the app using command line options is significantly less work than building out your own minimal GUI. So if this is for homework, I'd make a console app first. If you have extra time, then you can try implementing a GUI.

Comment: This assignment would take too much time from me so I'm going to change it. Anyway, thanks for your help. :)